How do I route time to chrony from TCP socket?
I have a modem that can forward GPS time to a TCP socket, these are GGPA sentences, I would like to get this information to chronyd so I can use chronyd as the single source of time sync in the system.
My first try was to add
refclock SOCK /tmp/gps.sock refid GPS precision 1e-1 poll 3

To the config, then use a simple program to create that socket, and forward the time to it.
However I do not see any evidence that chronyd is pulling time from this socket? (i've restarted, called makestep etc etc) What I am getting wrong?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

I'm trying to do something similar, but pulling time from a different (non-GPS) source. I think chrony should create the gps.sock for you once you put it in conf and restart, and your program should just write to it. Check chronyc sources to see if it's working.
For GPS though, I think it's more common to use gpsd to handle various format sentences and then configure chrony to get updates from gpsd either through SOCK or SHM. I tried this with a GPS source and I wasn't able to get SOCK to work but SHM worked once I had gpsd configured right and ntpshmmon was showing data.
